# How to type-safe add element to list whose generic extends class and implements interface?

Tags: java, generics

I'm looking for a type-safe, checked solution to add an element to a list whose generic requires both a class and an interface. The example illustrates what I'd like to do - add an object whose type `Cat` extends `Animal` and implements `Quadruped` to a list `List<T>` where `T extends Animal & Quadruped`.

```
class Example {
    public interface Quadruped { };
    public static class Animal { };
    public static class Cat extends Animal implements Quadruped { };

    public <T extends Animal & Quadruped> List<T> getQuadrupedAnimals(){
        List<T> result = new ArrayList<>();
        Cat cat = new Cat();
        result.add(cat); // compile error
        return result;
    }
}
```

Of course casting `cat` to `B` would resolve the compile error but that would be unchecked.

Is there any solution for this at all? If not, does anyone know the reason why the compiler does not allow this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> does anyone know the reason why the compiler does not allow this?

`T` is a *specific* Animal and Quadraped, chosen at the call site of `getQuadrupedAnimals()`.

Legal invocations of that method include:

```
List<Dog> listOfDogs = getQuadrupedAnimals();
List<Hamster> listOfHamsters = getQuadrupedAnimals();
```

so you can't put a `Cat` into that list (nor a `Dog` nor a `Hamster`, for that matter), because whatever you put in there might not be castable to the type the caller wants. (You can put literal `null` in the list, though).

The solution is to declare the return type as `List<Cat>` (or `List<? extends Cat>`, or `List<? super Cat>`), if you want to return a list containing `Cat`s.

---

An intersection type is only really useful if you use it in a parameter, e.g.

```
public <T extends Animal & Quadruped> List<T> getQuadrupedAnimals(T animal){
  return List.of(animal);
}
```

or

```
public <T extends Animal & Quadruped> int countLegs(List<T> animals){
  return 4 * animals.size();
}
```